# ProviderChangeSupport in ADF Web Application

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

Is there any class similar to `ProviderChangeSupport` in ADF web application development?

Answer (score 0):

ProviderChangeSupport is used to refresh the lists. If you want to do the same in ADF, you can use either partial trigger or backing beans. Bind a Rich element to your component and refresh that element from java class.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that. But what my issue is new values are updated in pojo classes but it is not reflecting in UI.

Answer (score 0):

call --> this.getviewobject().executequery();

put it in save method or other method you are using for every time you want to refresh your table.

// I was having same issue.

hope this would help you. let me know the answer

Comment: you have to put this in "impl" class.  And call through  -->                OperationBinding op1 = (OperationBinding)getBindings().get("methodName used in impl class for execute query");
                op1.execute();

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply .
I will update you once i have implemented your solution